# MarkLogic XQuery - How do I return a document if I have its URI?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

This is a simple question: I have the URI of a document, but what's the XQuery to return that single document from its URI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.marklogic.com/fn:doc

```
fn:doc(
   [$uri as xs:string*]
) as document-node()*
```

While learning XQuery, http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-use-cases/ can be a great resource. It introduces `fn:doc` right away, and then puts it to work in various examples. If you work through all the use cases you should end up with a pretty good grasp of XQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Got it.

```
fn:doc('/blah/blah.xml')
```

As simple as I expected.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg I can't accept my own answer for many hours. 2 days in fact.

Comment: @chris It is a complete answer. Use the `fn:doc` function. It's laughably simple, but its actually hard to Google.

Comment: @LukePuplett: But you _can_ improve it meanwhile. ;)